# Recursive select a table

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Now I need to create a view of a table in MySQL, the basic structure of the table is as follows:

```
create table mirror (
    ID                varchar(50)    not null primary key,
    PARENT_ID         varchar(50)    not null comment 'The id of its parent',
    CODE              varchar(50)    null comment 'Code of the component',
    NAME              varchar(500)   null comment 'Name of the component',
    UNIT              varchar(100)   null comment 'Unit of the component'
)
```

Now, the view is used to select all the child in the same table, you could see the pic of the table:[image].

As you can see, the Big Hammer, Small Hammer, Mini Hammer should be the children of Hammer, which the same to the Spanners, now the view is gonna get the data of Row 1 and Row 5, then add a cell to writes their children like "SP0001, SP0002, SP0003".

How can I create this view?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data, you need a self join and then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect all children of each parent:

```
SELECT m1.ID, m1.CODE,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m2.CODE) children
FROM mirror m1 LEFT JOIN mirror m2
ON m2.PARENT_ID = m1.ID
WHERE m1.PARENT_ID = 0
GROUP BY m1.ID, m1.CODE
```